# Bulma, SASS background color variable doesn't work

Tags: css, sass, background, frameworks, bulma

I'm trying to change the Bulma variable $navbar-item-hover-background-color to change the background color of a an item in my Bulma navbar when the mouse pointer is on the item, but it doesn't work, the color is still the same
This is my scss file

```
@charset "utf-8"
$blue1: #0070c0;
$blue2: #00259e;
$blue3: #285aff;

//custom Bulma color
$info: $blue2;
$primary: $blue3;

$lime: #05F554;

$navbar-item-hover-background-color: $lime;
@import "../node_modules/bulma/bulma.sass";
```

I'm following this guide https://bulma.io/documentation/components/navbar/#basic-navbar

Answer (score 0):

The order in your scss file should be:

1. Define your colors
2. Customizing sass variables
3. Importing Bulma
4. Importing Bulma extensions

Also it's better to only import the parts you need from Bulma instead of the whole `bulma.sass` file.
For example if you are only using the navbar you can try the following:

```
@charset "utf-8"
// Defining colors
$blue1: #0070c0;
$blue2: #00259e;
$blue3: #285aff;
$lime: #05F554;

// Customizing variables
$info: $blue2;
$primary: $blue3;
$navbar-item-hover-background-color: $lime;

// Importing Bulma
@import "../node_modules/bulma/sass/utilities/_all.sass";
@import "../node_modules/bulma/sass/base/_all.sass";
@import "../node_modules/bulma/sass/components/navbar.sass";
```

If you still have problems with your custom variables you can follow [this tutorial from the documentation](https://bulma.io/documentation/customize/with-node-sass/) to fully understand Bulma customization.